# write a list of ordered dictionaries to a csv file in 1 single column in python

Tags: python, csv

I have OrderedDict like

```
[OrderedDict([('mnemonic', 'VERS'), ('unit', ''), ('value', 2.0), ('description', 'CWLS LOG ASCII STANDARD - VERSION 2.0')]), OrderedDict([('mnemonic', 'WRAP'), ('unit', ''), ('value', 'NO'), ('description', 'One line per depth step')]), OrderedDict([('mnemonic', 'PROD'), ('unit', ''), ('value', ''), ('description', 'LAS Producer')]), OrderedDict([('mnemonic', 'PROG'), ('unit', ''), ('value', 'LASO 4.1'), ('description', 'LAS Program name and version')])]
```

I need to write it to a csv file in a single column rather than multiple rows.
The header should look like `mnemonic1,unit1,value1,description1,mnemonic2,unit2,value2,description2,…`

Comment: Please format your code and explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: "***I need to write it in a csv file in 1 single column***" - Can you share why you need such format? what do you plan to do with  *`csv`* after?

Comment: I need to join it further with some database data.
having multiple rows is increasing data volume

Comment: So you need a single line output will all `orderDict` items? python2 or 3?

Comment: yes. i am doing it in python 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use something like:

```
import collections
z = [collections.OrderedDict([('mnemonic', 'VERS'), ('unit', ''), ('value', 2.0), ('description', 'CWLS LOG ASCII STANDARD - VERSION 2.0')]), collections.OrderedDict([('mnemonic', 'WRAP'), ('unit', ''), ('value', 'NO'), ('description', 'One line per depth step')]), collections.OrderedDict([('mnemonic', 'PROD'), ('unit', ''), ('value', ''), ('description', 'LAS Producer')]), collections.OrderedDict([('mnemonic', 'PROG'), ('unit', ''), ('value', 'LASO 4.1'), ('description', 'LAS Program name and version')])]

final = ""
for k in z:
    final += "{},{},{},{},".format(k['mnemonic'], k['unit'], k['value'], k['description'])

with open('output.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write(final.rstrip(","))

# VERS,,2.0,CWLS LOG ASCII STANDARD - VERSION 2.0,WRAP,,NO,One line per depth step,PROD,,,LAS Producer,PROG,,LASO 4.1,LAS Program name and version
```

---

You basically need to iterate trough the `OrderedDict` items, access the keys (i.e.: `k['mnemonic']`) and write the results to a file.

Comment: thanks!!! it worked......can I create a custom header as well....like
mnemonic1,unit1,value1,description1,mnemonic2,unit2,value2,description2,.....